# issues with serving 2 django applications with apache in ubuntu server using wsgi

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, ssl, mod-wsgi

i'm trying to host a second domain in my ubuntu vps (domain2), i read online that is possible to host 2 domains in one vps (with one ip adress) yet i'm having some issues with it.

i have this configuration in apache2 ubuntu under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:

```
Define wsgi_daemon1 "domain1"
Define wsgi_daemon2 "domain2"

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /home/my_linux_user/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/my_linux_user/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/my_linux_user/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>    
    <IfDefine !wsgi_init>
        WSGIDaemonProcess ${wsgi_daemon1} python-path=/home/my_linux_user/myproject python-home=/home/my_linux_user/myproject/myprojectenv
        WSGIProcessGroup ${wsgi_daemon1}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/my_linux_user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py    
        Define wsgi_init 1
    </IfDefine>

ServerName domain1.tn
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tn/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.tn/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_project2.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_project2.log combined

    Alias /static /home/my_linux_user/project2/static
    <Directory /home/my_linux_user/project2/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/my_linux_user/project2/django_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>    
    <IfDefine !wsgi_init>
        WSGIDaemonProcess ${wsgi_daemon2} python-path=/home/my_linux_user/project2 python-home=/home/my_linux_user/project2/project2ENV
        WSGIProcessGroup ${wsgi_daemon2}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/my_linux_user/project2/django_project/wsgi.py    
        Define wsgi_init 1
    </IfDefine>


ServerName domain2
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

the first domain is served correctly but the second domain (domain2) is not, it actually still pointing to the default apache2 index page

i tried

- restarting apache2 with:

```
apachectl restart
```

and with

```
apachectl graceful
```

- checking the DNS configuration, the domaain in up and working
- when i tried to just point the domain with a seperate vhost and a simple web page it works!, yet with wsgi it doesn't
- i tried to see what are the enabled sites with

```
apache2ctl -S
```

and i something like this:

```
*:443 is a NameVirtualHost
default server domain1.tn (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:5)
port 443 namevhost domain1.tn (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:5)
port 443 namevhost domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:106)
port 443 namevhost mail.domain1.tn
(/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mail.domain1.tn.conf:3)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: MODSEC_2.5
Define: MODSEC_2.9
Define: wsgi_daemon1=domain1
Define: wsgi_daemon2=domain2
Define: wsgi_init=1
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

so my question does it take some time for changes to take effect (it was not the case when i hosted the first domain (domain1)), if not i will appreciate any help :)

ps: i'm replacing the actual domain names